# vue integration test with axios and real server calls

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js, vue-test-utils

Beeing new to vue testing, I'm trying to make an integration test for our Vue SPA with axios & mocha.

I want some of the tests to make **real** api calls to our server **without mocking**, to figure out if it really works from the beginning to the end. The server API is a Laravel 7 app with laravel/sanctum and cookie based session authentication.

I can make real axios calls directly in the test file like this:

```
import authApi from '../../src/components/connections/auth';

describe('AxiosCallTest', () => {
  it('makes an axios call', function(done) {
    this.timeout(5000);

    authApi.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then((response) => {
      console.log('response: ', JSON.stringify(response));
      done();
    }).catch(() => {
      done();
    });
  });
});

// -> response:  {"data":"","status":204,"statusText":"No Content","headers":{"cache-control":"no-cache, private"},"config":{"url":"/sanctum/csrf-cookie","method":"get","headers":{"Accept":"application/json","X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"},"baseURL":"http://testing.backend.vipany.test/api/auth","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":30000,"withCredentials":true,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"axios-retry":{"retryCount":0,"lastRequestTime":1591774391768}},"request":{"upload":{"_ownerDocument":{"location":{"href":"http://localhost/","origin":"http://localhost","protocol":"http:","host":"localhost","hostname":"localhost","port":"","pathname":"/","search":"","hash":""}}},"_registeredHandlers":{},"_eventHandlers":{}}}
```

I've read and tried a lot and now have 2 problems:

- handling cookies for CSRF Token Cookies and Session Cookies (used for authentication), as on conventional requests the browser handles this out of the box.
- waiting on axios calls in vue components, as I can't use mocha's done() function in the components itself, as I did in this example. I can only find examples with mocking requests with moxios or similiar. But I don't want to mock the axios calls.

Does anyone know a good article about these issues or has already solved it?

Thanks a lot

---

**update**:

I've found an [article](https://jacobruiz.com/blog/2019/6/26/how-to-test-cookie-based-authentication-in-mocha-with-axios-node-graphql-apollo) to get the cookie out of the axios request and tried it myself to get the X-XSRF-TOKEN out of the response (I've checked it in the browser: HttpOnly: false, secure: false), but it does not work:

```
  console.log('response X-XSRF-TOKEN: ', response.config.headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN']); 
  // -> undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that [cypress](https://www.cypress.io) and [nightwatch](https://nightwatchjs.org) are the right tools for end-to-end testing (e2).
Didn't know the right terms (e2e or end-to-end testing) and the right tools.

Switched to cypress.io - absolutly great.

vue-cli even has first hand plugins to integrate cypress or nightwatch: https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/e2e-cypress.html